# Selenium C# - How to click on a link in a cell based on another cell in the same row?

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Using Selenium WEbdriver and C#, I am trying to click on a link in a cell based on the value in another cell. Here is the basic HTML:

```
<table id="MainContent_gvInvoices">
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td>120109524</td>
    <td>12345678</td>
    <td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$gvInvoices','Edit$0')">Edit</a></td>
</tr>
```

So, in the above HTML, first cell is lets say a Customer ID. The last cell in the same row is a link called 'Edit'. There could be multiple rows like these with different Customer Ids. I need to click on the Edit link based on a Customer ID. So far I have tried this with no luck:

```
public IWebElement testtable { get { return Driver.FindElement(By.Id("MainContent_gvInvoices")); } }
public IList<IWebElement> rows { get { return testtable.FindElements(By.CssSelector("tbody tr td")); } }
public IWebElement Edit { get { return Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='MainContent_gvInvoices']/tbody/tr[text() = '120109524']/td[3]/a")); } }
```

After this, `Edit.Click()` throws nusuchelement exception. How can I implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`following-sibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/following-sibling) and `last()`:

```
//table[@id='MainContent_gvInvoices']/td[. = '120109524']/following-sibling::td[last()]
```

Comment: public IWebElement Edit { get { return Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//table[@id='MainContent_gvInvoices']/tbody/tr/td[. = '120109524']/following-sibling::td/a")); } }

Answer (score 0):

You can use `By.CssSelector` and the `href`, i imagine the zero its the row index, so you would have to change that if you have more

```
By.CssSelector("a[href*='Edit$0']");
```